# How to make TicketNetwork widget display "No results found"?

Tags: javascript

I wasn't sure how to search for the answer to this on here or on Google, so I figured I would just ask. I'm an affiliate for TicketNetwork and they have a plugin generator (you can see it here if you want: http://www.ticketnetwork.com/affiliates/plug-in-maker.aspx) where you can put in a keyword and it generates a list of events based on that keyword (basically like doing a search on their site). Here's an example of the code you'd put on your site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function TN_SetWidgetOptions() {
        TN_Widget.newWindow = true;
        TN_Widget.trackingParams = '';
        TN_Widget.custLink = true;
        TN_Widget.tixUrl = 'http://www.ticketnetwork.com/tix/';
        TN_Widget.trackingLink = 'http://www.tkqlhce.com/click-12345-10793961?url=';
        TN_Widget.CreateCustomUrl = function(row) {
            return "http://www.tkqlhce.com/click-12345-10793961?url=" + escape(this.tixUrl +  row[7] + "-tickets-"+ row[6] + ".aspx");
        };
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://site_01504_011.ticketsoftware.net/widget3_c.aspx?kwds=austin%20city%20limits%20festival&style=9&mxrslts=10"></script>
```

My problem is, if a keyword returns no results, instead of giving some sort of "no results found", it just shows blank space. Is there some way I can manipulate this code to make it show something other than blank space if there are no results, or is that something TicketNetwork would have to add into their plugin generator?

Comment: Could you please make this code more readable? Also, it would be helpful if you put this in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this in JQuery (Pseudocode)

```
if ($.trim($("#DIV").text()) === '') {
document.write('No Results Returned');
}
```

Just replace the DIV with the ID of the html tags surrounding your output. This is untested so you might have to fiddle with it a little bit but I think this is something that would work.

Also, don't forget you'll have to include the JQuery files to get this to work also.

EDIT: You can use `$('#DIVID').text('No results Returned');` to point your code to wherever you want to display the text by JQuery selector.

Answer (score 0):

First I just want to say thanks to the people who tidied up my question for me.

With the help of Bryant's answer I devised this solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var nodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("TD").length;
if (nodelist == 0){
document.write("No tickets for this event are currently available.")
}
</script>
```

When there are no results, all it creates is an empty table with no cells. So, I just check if any table cells exist, and if there are none, it writes my message. I tried like a hundred different things before I landed on this, but I'm glad it works! :)